# traducción consulta eloquent a consulta por rangos between

Tags: laravel-5

Alguien sabe como puedo traducir esta consulta a eloquent correctamente?

```
select * 
from usuarios 
where created_at BETWEEN '2018-10-20' AND '2018-11-03';
```

Comment: `$user=User::whereBetween("created_at",['2018-10-20' , '2018-11-03'])->get();`, o tambien puedes hacer `$user=User::whereDate("created_at",">=",'2018-10-20')->whereDate("created_at","<=", '2018-11-03')->get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu tabla usuarios la tienes vinculada por algún modelo, que por ejemplo se llame `User` puedes tener tu consulta de este modo

```
$data = User::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-10-20', '2018-11-03'])->get();
```

**Explicación**

Donde como puedes ver hacemos uso del método `whereBetween()` que recibe tres parámetros, el primero es el nombre de la columna, el segundo la fecha desde la cual se va a buscar y el tercero la fecha hasta la cual se va a buscar.

**ALTERNATIVA**

```
$data = \DB::table('usuarios')
         ->whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-10-20', '2018-11-03'])
         ->get();
```

**ACLARACIÓN**

Si tu columna `created_at` tiene un dato de tipo `2018-10-10 09:40:14` entonces es necesario que coloques año-mes-dia hora:minuto:segundo así: `2018-10-10 09:40:14`

**EJEMPLO**

```
$data = User::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-10-10 09:40:14', '2018-10-10 09:40:14'])
->get();
```

Revisa bien el tipo de dato que almacenas como te hago la observación y vas a obtener el resultado deseado

Enlace a la documentación oficial, sobre el método `whereBetween()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: Muchas gracias shadow, ya pude arreglar mi metodo, muy completa la explicacion